# Sequential relationship table alignment error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sql-server, next.js, sequelize.js

The **`post`** and **`user`** tables in my project form the relationship between the following tables.

```
// models/post.js
static associate(db) {
  db.Post.belongsTo(db.User);
  db.Post.belongsToMany(db.Hashtag, { through: 'PostHashtag' });
  db.Post.hasMany(db.Comment);
  db.Post.hasMany(db.Image);
  db.Post.belongsToMany(db.User, { through: 'Like', as: 'Likers' });    
}
```

```
// models/user.js
static associate(db) { 
  db.User.hasMany(db.Post);
  db.User.hasMany(db.Comment);
  db.User.belongsToMany(db.Post, { through: 'Like', as: 'Liked' })     
}
```

Using the **`Liked`** relationship table, the posts are sorted in the order they like them as follows.

Posts sorted in this way include a comment table.

```
router.get('/liked', isLoggedIn, async (req, res, next) => { // loadLikedPostAPI / GET /user/liked
  try {
    const likedPosts = await User.findAll({   
      where: { id: req.user.id },      
      attributes: [],
      order: [
        // Sorted in the order in which likes were clicked    
        [Sequelize.literal("(`Liked->Like`.`createdAt`)"), "DESC"],     
      ],      
      include: [{
        model: Post,
        as: 'Liked',        
        include: [{
          model: User,
          attributes: ['id', 'nickname'],
        }, {
          model: User,
          as: 'Likers',
          attributes: ['id'],
        }, {
          model: Comment,          
          include: [{
            model: User,
            attributes: ['id', 'nickname'],
          }],
        }, {
          model: Image,
        }]
      }],
    });
```

As a result of running it, I was able to successfully get the data I wanted.

Afterwards, I wanted to sort the comments of the sorted posts in descending order, so I did an additional sort as follows.

```
order: [
  [Sequelize.literal("(`Liked->Like`.`createdAt`)"), "DESC"],        
  // Sort the comments of the sorted posts in descending order.
  [Comment, 'createdAt', 'DESC'],
],
```

However, the execution result was different from my expectations and resulted in the following error:

```
code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
    errno: 1054,
    sqlState: '42S22',
    sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'Comments.createdAt' in 'order clause'",
    sql: 'SELECT `User`.`id`, `Liked`.`id` AS `Liked.id`, `Liked`.`title` AS `Liked.title`, `Liked`.`desc` AS `Liked.desc`, `Liked`.`ingredient` AS `Liked.ingredient`, `Liked`.`recipes` AS `Liked.recipes`, `Liked`.`tips` AS `Liked.tips`, `Liked`.`tags` AS `Liked.tags`, `Liked`.`createdAt` AS `Liked.createdAt`, `Liked`.`updatedAt` AS `Liked.updatedAt`, `Liked`.`UserId` AS `Liked.UserId`, 
`Liked->Like`.`createdAt` AS `Liked.Like.createdAt`, `Liked->Like`.`updatedAt` AS `Liked.Like.updatedAt`, `Liked->Like`.`PostId` AS `Liked.Like.PostId`, `Liked->Like`.`UserId` AS `Liked.Like.UserId`, `Liked->User`.`id` AS `Liked.User.id`, `Liked->User`.`nickname` AS `Liked.User.nickname`, `Liked->Likers`.`id` AS `Liked.Likers.id`, `Liked->Likers->Like`.`createdAt` AS `Liked.Likers.Like.createdAt`, `Liked->Likers->Like`.`updatedAt` AS `Liked.Likers.Like.updatedAt`, `Liked->Likers->Like`.`PostId` AS `Liked.Likers.Like.PostId`, `Liked->Likers->Like`.`UserId` AS `Liked.Likers.Like.UserId`, `Liked->Comments`.`id` AS `Liked.Comments.id`, `Liked->Comments`.`content` AS `Liked.Comments.content`, `Liked->Comments`.`createdAt` AS `Liked.Comments.createdAt`, `Liked->Comments`.`updatedAt` AS `Liked.Comments.updatedAt`, `Liked->Comments`.`UserId` AS `Liked.Comments.UserId`, `Liked->Comments`.`PostId` AS `Liked.Comments.PostId`, `Liked->Comments->User`.`id` AS `Liked.Comments.User.id`, `Liked->Comments->User`.`nickname` AS `Liked.Comments.User.nickname`, `Liked->Images`.`id` AS `Liked.Images.id`, `Liked->Images`.`src` AS `Liked.Images.src`, `Liked->Images`.`createdAt` AS `Liked.Images.createdAt`, `Liked->Images`.`updatedAt` AS `Liked.Images.updatedAt`, `Liked->Images`.`PostId` AS `Liked.Images.PostId` FROM `users` AS `User` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `Like` AS `Liked->Like` INNER JOIN `posts` AS `Liked` ON `Liked`.`id` = `Liked->Like`.`PostId`) ON `User`.`id` = `Liked->Like`.`UserId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `Liked->User` ON `Liked`.`UserId` = `Liked->User`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN ( `Like` AS `Liked->Likers->Like` INNER JOIN `users` AS `Liked->Likers` ON `Liked->Likers`.`id` = `Liked->Likers->Like`.`UserId`) ON `Liked`.`id` = `Liked->Likers->Like`.`PostId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` AS `Liked->Comments` ON `Liked`.`id` = `Liked->Comments`.`PostId` LEFT OUTER JOIN `users` AS `Liked->Comments->User` ON `Liked->Comments`.`UserId` = `Liked->Comments->User`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `images` AS `Liked->Images` ON `Liked`.`id` = `Liked->Images`.`PostId` WHERE `User`.`id` = 8 ORDER BY (`Liked->Like`.`createdAt`) DESC, `Comments`.`createdAt` DESC;',
    parameters: undefined
  },
```

I've been trying for days to fix the problem, but I can't find it.

What measures should be taken to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need all associations from the top. Because you have `Comment` which is included within `Post`, you need something like this.

```
order: [
    [Sequelize.literal("`Liked->Like`.`createdAt`"), "DESC"],
    [{model: Post, as:'Liked'}, Comment, 'createdAt', 'DESC']
]
```

Comment: Thanks Emma, thanks to you, I was able to solve my problem